# Select record where value equals value of id

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

This is a simple but hard to describe question

```
await dbContext.MyTable.AnyAsync(x => x.valueOne == valueOne && x.valueTwo == /*here's my problem*/ );
```

`valueOne` is getting passed in as a parameter. The end of the statement in pseudocode would be:

`x.valueTwo == the valueTwo of valueOne's record`

I know I could pull in valueOne's record and compare from there, but that's clumsier and I feel like there's definitely a better way if only I could find it.
How can I do this in one line?

**Edit:** clarification

To clarify, the clumsy way would be

```
var valueOneRecord = await dbContext.MyTable.FirstAsync(x => x.valueOne == valueOne);
exists = await dbContext.MyTable.AnyAsync(x => x.valueOne == valueOne && x.valueTwo == valueOneRecord.valueTwo);
```

I'm trying to merge this into one line instead of having two database requests

Comment: _...&& x.valueTwo == x.valueOne..._ doesn't work?

Comment: No, they're two different columns

Comment: Can you explain better your requirements? I understand that you want to check if any record exists in _MyTable_ whose value in the column _valueOne_ is equal to the variable _valueOne_ and has the value in column _valueTwo_ equal to the value in the column _valueOne_ in the SAME record. Is that right?

Comment: First part correct - I need the record whose *valueOne* value is equal to the variable *valueOne*, and whose *valueTwo* value is equal to the *valueTwo* of *valueOne*'s row

Comment: added clarification

Comment: Sorry but I really don't understand your logic. First you search the MyTable to find a record with a certain value in a certain column. Then you use that record to search if a record with those value exists. Of course it exists. You have just retrieved it. The only thing to change is FirstOrDefault instead of First, so you can test if the result is null and no need to do the second test

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below

```
        dbContext.MyTable.Join(dbContext.MyTable,
            x => new {
                x.valueOne,
                valueTwo = x.valueOne
            },
            y => new {
                y.valueOne,
                y.valueTwo
            },
            (x, y) => new
            {
                record1_valueOne = x.valueOne,
                record1_valueTwo = x.valueTwo,
                record2_valueOne = y.valueOne,
                record2_valueTwo = y.valueTwo,
            }).Where(x => x.record1_valueOne == valueOneParam && x.record2_valueOne == valueOneParam);
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite often it is easier for us if you give us your requirement instead of giving us some code and say that the code is not working.

Let's assume that your clumsy method is what you want.

So MyTable is a sequence of objects, let's call them Values. Every Value has at least two properties: ValueOne and ValueTwo. You also have an input value: valueOne.

Suppose you had Schools and Students, every School had a primary key in Id, and a State

```
class School
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int CityId {get; set;}
    ...
}

public class Student
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public int CityId {get; set;}
}
```

A note so strange query would be:

> Give me all Students that live in the same City as School 10

```
int schoolId = 10;
var studentsInSameCityAsSchool10 = dbContext.Schools

    // keep only school with Id == 10
    .Where(school => school.Id == 10)

    // get all Students on these Schools
    .GroupJoin(dbContext.Students,
        school => school.CityId,
        student => student.CityId,

        (school, studentsWithSameCityId) => new
        {
           SchoolId = school.Id,
           Students = studentsWithSameCityId.Select(student => new
           {
               StudentId = student.Id,
               Name = student.Name,
               ...
           })
           .ToList(),
        });
```

Very straightforward, isn't it. Now let's do a query in just one table:

> Give me all Schools with the same CityId as School [10]

```
int schoolId = 10;
var studentsInSameCityAsSchool10 = dbContext.Schools

    // keep only school with Id == 10
    .Where(school => school.Id == 10)

    // get all Students on these Schools
    .GroupJoin(dbContext.Students,
        school => school.CityId,
        student => student.CityId,

        (school, studentsWithSameCityId) => new
        {
           SchoolId = school.Id,
           Students = studentsWithSameCityId.Select(student => new
           {
               StudentId = student.Id,
               Name = student.Name,
               ...
           })
           .ToList(),
        });
```

Very straightforward, isn't it. Now let's do a query in just one table:

> Give me all Schools with the same CityId as School [10]

```
int schoolId = 10;
var studentsInSameCityAsSchool10 = dbContext.Schools

    // keep only school with Id == 10
    .Where(school => school.Id == 10)

    // get all Students on these Schools
    .Join(dbContext.Students,                 // Join Schools and Students
        school => school.CityId,              // from every School take the CityId
        student => student.CityId,            // from every Student take the CityId

        (school, studentWithSameCityId) => new  // from every School and every Student
        {                                       // that has the same CityId, make one new
            SchoolId = school.Id,
            CityId = school.CityId,
            StudentThatLiveInCityId = studentWithSameCityId,
        });
```

Very straightforward, isn't it? Now let's do a query in just one table:

> Give me all Schools with the same CityId as School [10]

```
int schoolId = 10;
var studentsInSameCityAsSchool10 = dbContext.Schools
    .Where(school => school.Id == 10)

    // get all Schools in the same City as School[10]
    .Join(dbContext.Schools,                 // Join Schools and Schools
        school1 => school1.CityId,           // from every School1 take the CityId
        school2 => school2.CityId,           // from every School2 take the CityId

        (school1, school2WithSameCityId) => new  // from every School and every School
        {                                        // that has the same CityId, make one new
           ...
        });
```

**But what does this have to do with my question**

Now let's change some of the property names:

```
class School
{
    public int ValueOne {get; set;}  // was Id
    public int ValueTwo {get; set;}  // was CityId
}

int valueOne = 10; // was schoolId
```

> Give me all Schools that have the same ValueTwo (was: located in the same City, or has same cityId) as School with ValueOne == valueOne (was: as School [10])

After the exercizes with Schools and Students this one should be easy:

```
int valueOne = 10;
var valuesWithSameValueTwo = dbContext.Schools
    .Where(value => value.ValueOne == 10)

    // get all Values with same ValueTwo Value[10]
    .Join(dbContext.Schools,             // Join Schools and Schools
        val1 => val1.ValueTwo,           // from every val1 take the ValueTwo
        val2 => val2.ValueTwo,           // from every val2 take the ValueTwo

        (val, valWithSameValueTwoId) => new
        { 
          ...
        });
```

Well, your query is easier: you only want to know if there is any such element. So you don't need to select any properties, and you can stop as soon as you've found one:

```
 // Where and Join:
 ...
 (val, valWithSameValueTwoId) => valWithSameTwoId)

 .Any();
```